# What is the cost of emulating ring arithmetic (say modulo $2^k$) over a prime finite field?

Tags: multiparty-computation

Several papers in, for example, the domain of Secure Multiparty Computation, are set in the context in which the computation domain is a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, while some more recent works (e.g. SPDZ2k [1]) are set over a (non-field) ring $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}$. In some cases, however, the latter-type of protocols carry some overheads.

I wonder:

> What would be the cost of emulating arithmetic modulo $2^k$, when having access to arithmetic modulo a prime $p$?

I don't even know what would be a natural approach to such task, even though every computation can be emulated with field arithmetic. I would split this into two cases: $p=2$ and $p>2^k$. In the former, a $k$-bit adder can be used, whose complexity is well known. For the latter, the situation is more unclear.

[1] R. Cramer, I. Damgård, D. Escudero, P. Scholl, and C. Xing, “SPDZ2k: Efficient MPC mod 2^k for Dishonest Majority,” in Advances in Cryptology – CRYPTO 2018, 2018, pp. 769–798.

Comment: I spent some time looking at this problem this summer and found nothing. The best I could find is to emulate $p=2$ with arbitrary $p$: If you restrict to $\{0,1\}$ values, then you can implement AND$(x,y)=xy$, XOR$(x,y)=x+y-xy$, and NOT$(x)=1-x$. All of these work for $x,y$ modulo $p$ for arbitrary $p$. From there you can build any circuit, but of course very inefficiently.

A major obstacle to using a $p$-ary decomposition (like in binary) is carry bits: in binary these are easy to calculate, but not for $p>2$ because comparators don't exist.

Comment: @SamJaques $XOR(x,y) = x+y-2xy$